# cProfile streamline -- python

Tags: python, profiler

I'm trying to profile a python script with several functions in it. Here is the code I'm using to profile the program:

```
cProfile.run('loadBMPImage(sys.argv[1])')
cProfile.run('parseFilterCmdArgs(sys.argv)')
cProfile.run('doConvolution( img_data, filter_width, filter_weights, img_height, img_width )')
cProfile.run('saveBMPImage(out_img_data, header_data, sys.argv[2], img_height, img_width )')
```

So I see 4 profile reports in standard out.
However, I was wondering if there was a way to do this more smoothly, and show ONE profile report for all 4 of these functions? Better yet, is there a way to profile the entire program with one call of `cProfile`? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Easy. Just make one function that calls these 4 with all necessary arguments.

To profile a whole script as a separate program, you actually can call cProfile from the command line.

➜  ~  py3 -m cProfile --help
  Usage: cProfile.py [-o output_file_path] [-s sort] scriptfile [arg] ...

Options:
      -h, --help            show this help message and exit
      -o OUTFILE, --outfile=OUTFILE
                            Save stats to 
      -s SORT, --sort=SORT  Sort order when printing to stdout, based on
                            pstats.Stats class